# Select only rows with common status from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have table as follows:

```
ID CustomerID  AccountNumber StatusID
-------------------------------------
1     300          300100       1
2     300          300200       3
3     300          300300       3
4     400          400100       1
5     400          400200       1
6     500          500100       1
```

StatusID:

- 1 = Approved
- 3 = Pending

Now I need to select all customers whose accounts are approved (none are pending), but not customers whose accounts are still pending.

Please let me know if you need more details from my end.

Comment: Kindly provide what the expected result is and what you have tried out for this

Comment: Expected results is: I need customerID whose status is 1 (I mean all accounts related to that customer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the another simple way to do basing on your sample data provided

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    T.ID, 
    T.CustomerID  , 
    T.AccountNumber , 
    T.StatusID 
FROM 
    Table1 T
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT CID 
     FROM @Table1 
     WHERE StatusID = 3) TT ON T.CID <> TT.CID
```

Answer (score 4):

Group by the customer and take only those having no `status <> 1`

```
select customerID
from your_table
group by customerID
having sum(case when status <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: probably best/flexible approach out of all answers

Answer (score 3):

Use **HAVING** Clause with **MAX**, it will give you all customers who has only status "Approved" =1

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID
FROM @tblTest
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING MAX(StatusID)=1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to get a list of all customers with pending accounts:

```
select customerID
from your_table
where StatusID = 3
```

And thus just select data where customer is not in the above:

```
select distinct CustomerID
from your_table
where CustomerID not in (select customerID
                         from your_table
                         where StatusID = 3)
```

(`distict` to avoid duoplicates.)

Answer (score 0):

The first answer seems to work.Another alternative way would be to do this which is a bit lengthy though

```
 select distinct customerid from 
 (
  select customerid,count(1) as cnt 
  from 
 (select customerid,statusID,count(1) as cnt 
  from ids 
  group by customerid,statusid)a
  group by customerid
  having count(1)=1
)a
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an another way of doing is with simple self join.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (ID INT, CustomerID INT,  AccountNumber VARCHAR(20), StatusID INT)

INSERT INTO #TAB

SELECT 1,300,300100,  1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,300,300200,  3
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,300,300300,  3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,400,400100,  1
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,400,400200,  1
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,500,500100,  1
```

And make a Self Join like below, and filter with Where clause who are having pending status records.

```
SELECT AP.* FROM #TAB AP
LEFT JOIN #TAB P ON AP.CustomerID = p.CustomerID
AND P.StatusID=3 
WHERE AP.StatusID=1
AND P.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple query like below to get the all customers whose accounts are approved

```
select distinct(customerID) 
from your_table 
where StatusID = 1
```